# JSF: How to execute some code on every time a navigation rule is executed?

Tags: jsf, navigation, jsf-1.2, journey

Is there any way I can execute some code whenever a `navigation rule` is executed. Basically what I am trying to do is to have a `JourneyTracker` bean which will hold the current state of the journey (like the current page the user is in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom [`NavigationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html) for this. Basically, just extend that abstract class as follows:

```
public class MyNavigationHandler extends NavigationHandler {

    private NavigationHandler wrapped;

    public MyNavigationHandler(NavigationHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNavigation(FacesContext context, String from, String outcome) {
        // Do your job here. Just check if "from" and/or "outcome" matches the desired rule.

        wrapped.handleNavigation(context, from, outcome); // Important! This will perform the actual navigation.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, just register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <navigation-handler>com.example.MyNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
</application>
```

Comment: @BaluC Awesome! It worked. Is there any way to figure out the next view-id? handleNavigation just gives fromAction and outcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You can however use `fromAction` and `outcome` to manually/programmatically perform a navigation by `NavigationHandler` as obtained by `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler()`.

Comment: Is there a `@Annotation` for using it without editing `faces-config.xml`?

Comment: P.S. Why using this handler causing messages like `service jboss.deployment.unit."project-web-1.0.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (no longer required)` and some links have attached messages like `This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched.`?

Comment: @T.G Hint: question is about JSF 1.x. You need to look for a JSF 2.x targeted question&answer.